# Grafana does not send notifications through reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, proxypass, grafana

I am using Grafana on a server that does not have Internet, I need to send Telegram notifications, for that I am using Nginx server in another machine.

**Server A:**

- Grafana installed / Running on port 3000.
- Grafana url: [www.example.grafana.com](http://www.example.grafana.com)
- IP of the server (example): 10.16.216.122
- It uses this webhook to send telegram messages: api.telegram.org
- I also configured /etc/hosts to send that notifications to my server:

```
#/etc/hosts
10.16.216.16  api.telegram.org
```

**Server B:**

- IP of the server (example): 10.16.216.16
- Nginx installed, with this config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 http2 ssl;

    server_name http://10.16.216.122;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.16.216.122:3000/;
    }}
```

When I try to send the notification, I receive this in the logs:

```
t=2021-10-27T17:10:07+0200 lvl=eror msg="Failed to send webhook" logger=alerting.notifier.telegram error="Post https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXX/sendMessage: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)" webhook=TelegramTest
t=2021-10-27T17:10:07+0200 lvl=eror msg="failed to send notification" logger=alerting.notifier uid= error="Post https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendMessage: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
t=2021-10-27T17:10:07+0200 lvl=eror msg="failed to send notification" logger=alerting.notifier uid= error="Post https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendMessage: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
t=2021-10-27T17:10:07+0200 lvl=eror msg="Failed to send alert notifications" logger=context userId=51 orgId=5 uname=XXXX error="Post https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendMessage: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
t=2021-10-27T17:10:07+0200 lvl=eror msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=51 orgId=5 uname=XXXXX method=POST path=/api/alert-notifications/test status=500 remote_addr=10.26.216.122 time_ms=30006 size=48 referer=http://10.26.216.122/alerting/notification/1/edit
```

Am I missing something in my configuration on Nginx? Does the Server A need something more to work?

Answer (score 1):

Webhooks is a outgoing connection from grafana. The reverse proxy handles incoming connections.

If you want to proxy outgoing connections as well, you have to configure a normal, forward proxy, *and* configure Grafana to use this for outgoing requests.

Comment: Could you please put an example about how to config that?

Comment: https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-use-nginx-as-an-https-forward-proxy-server_595799 first hit googling for 'nginx forward proxy'.